# Can't open an SSH session because of OpenSSL version mismatch

Tags: ssh, debian, apt-get, openssl

I just ran `apt-get upgrade`, and according to /var/log/apt/history.log, openssl has been updated to version 1.0.1e-2+rvt+deb7u7. Now I have one SSH session still open, but I can't open another one. I restarted SSH, which returned `OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000105f, you have 10001080`. 
I tried `apt-get remove openssl && apt-get install openssl` with no luck. I'm running debian on a raspberry pi.

Edit: I should mention that I'm running wheezy, and used the jessie repository to get the latest PHP5 version. I forgot to switch back before `apt-get upgrade`-ing.

Edit 2: problem solved;

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Did the trick ([source](http://ispire.me/downgrade-from-debian-sid-to-stable-from-jessie-to-wheezy/)).

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

From [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24247580/):

> Try `apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client`.
>
> I had the same issue when I updated my system to Debian Testing. Even though SSH was already installed, in my case it wasn't pulled in for updating when I ran apt-get update && apt-get upgrade and so the system still had the same SSH binaries with the now-outdated libraries linked against it, hence the version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your ssh is having a port conflict. From searching around i found 3 commands that might be able to help. SIGHUP, SIGKILL and SIGTERM. From what the article i found on it was SIGTERM is the safest way to kill the process blocking the port.

When i programmed in python, it wouldn't kill the process even when i exited the gui. so those might work for ya.

Reference from 
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/kill-process-in-linux-or-terminate-a-process-in-unix-or-linux-systems/

Comment: Also there may be other programs trying to use the same port,
i would reccomend using the command i posted below to view running processes on your system. 

 # ps aux | less

Answer (score -1):

I got this

OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 100020ef, you have 1000106f

My fix: I downgraded from VirtualBox-6.1  to 5.2.